# Why are 3rd party libraries not found on the OCaml search path?

Tags: macos, build, ocaml, llvm, homebrew

My configuration is as follows:

OCaml is installed by Homebrew, according to its default recipe. It lives in `/usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/3.12.0/[bin,lib,share]`, the contents of which are symlinked out to `/usr/local/[bin,lib,share]`.

A 3rd party library (LLVM) installed symlinks into `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/*`. Critically, `/usr/local/lib/ocaml` is itself *not* a symlink to the Homebrew Cellar, but a folder containing links to the individual files under the OCaml Cellar path, so these 3rd party library files are in the `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/` path but not the original path of

The standard OCaml compilers/interpreter/build tools consistently fail to find these 3rd party libraries unless they are explicitly pointed there (e.g. with `ocamlbuild -cflags -I,/usr/local/lib/ocaml`).

`ld.conf` lists:

```
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/stublibs
/usr/local/lib/ocaml
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/site-lib/pcre
```

which would seem to suggest that the compiler search path be set correctly, but I am not familiar with the inner workings of the toolchain.

- Is this a known problem?
- Is there a way to print the OCaml search paths actually used by the standard tools?
- Assuming this is a consequence of the Homebrew `configure` and installation process (i.e. assuming that the problem is OCaml, as configured, assuming its actual lib path is `/usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/3.12.0/lib/ocaml` rather than `/usr/local/lib/ocaml`), is it possible to force explicitly add additional search paths outside the `--prefix` during configuration?
- Is it possible to extend the search paths for the entire environment after installation (by editing config files, rather than having to resort to potential reinstallation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only builtin search path for ocaml modules is the path to stdlib - see it with `ocamlc -where`. Paths referenced in ld.conf are used to find stublibs - C code compiled to dynamically loadable modules for bytecode ocaml programs using C bindings (without custom runtime). There is no way to "extend" search paths globally wrt ocaml installation.

The correct way is to add needed include paths when invoking ocaml tools. `ocamlfind` tool greatly helps to do this in system-independent way. E.g.:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -package llvm ll.ml -o ll
```

High-level build systems like oasis/ocamlbuild/omake/etc hide all this stuff altogether and user only needs to provide names of dependent packages.

Comment: ocamlc -where indeed reports the Cellar location: /usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/3.12.0/lib/ocaml. And llvm does not seem to be installing a findlib META file, which would explain its absence. Your ocamlfind suggestion does not fix the problem, presumably for this reason.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed as ygrek pointed out, the answer is `ocamlfind`. OCamlfind maintains a list of findlib-enabled¹ OCaml packages installed on your system, and it's easy to link them. Use

```
ocamlfind list
```

To get the list of packages, which can be piped to `grep` etc.

```
ocamlfind query mypackage
```

To get the installation path for the package (for more see `ocamlfind query --help`)

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package mypackage .....
```

To compile something using the package as a dependency (`-linkpkg` is used in the final linking step to build the executable, you don't need it with `-c -o foo.cmo` for example).

`ocamlfind` can also be used through [ocamlbuild](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Ocamlbuild). Prior to ocaml 3.12 you add to hack a bit the `myocamlbuild.ml` file ([link](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Using_ocamlfind_with_ocamlbuild)), but since 3.12 it's dead easy: use `package(foo)` in the ocamlbuild tags if you want to use ocamlfind's package `foo`, and add option `-use-ocamlfind` to `ocamlbuild`'s invocation.

¹: ocamlfind is the lingua franca of OCaml packages. If some of your third libraries don't register themselves through ocamlfind, you should hunt them, write a META file (it's easy), and send it to the library maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for $CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH  to specify locations of additional libraries to link to, cfr. http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scott/pl/caml/htmlman/manual024.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `OCAMLLIB` environment variable to get the result you're looking for.  This is documented to help `ocamlrun` find the `ld.conf` file you noted in your question, but might also help you with `ocamlc`.  The core distribution of OCaml doesn't have a configuration file for library paths, only the config file for locating C libraries.